# How page Navigation in JQ grid & page number search box if we search wrong page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am facing problem in jqgrid page navigation.

Suppose in my jqgrid I had 10 pages and I navigated to the 5th page. If I entered page number 15 in page search box, then it should display warning box like "your entered page number 15 is not available". It's ok but the actual problem is: it is navigating to the 1st page again and it should not be like that. Actually it should go to previous page i.e the 5th page.

How to solve this problem?
I am using the code like:

```
var currentpage=$(".ui-pg-input").val();
var rowNum = jQuery("#list").getGridParam('rowNum');
var allRecords = jQuery("#list").getGridParam('records');
var totalPages = parseInt((allRecords / rowNum) + 1);

if((totalPages < currentpage)) {

    alert("There is no page number "+currentpage)
    window.location.href=$("#applicationUrl").val()+'/abcdef/abcdef';


}
```

Comment: You can save the current page number and then reload the grid with that page number after you display the error.

Comment: Hi Dipen, Thanks for ur comment, can u give some sample code

Comment: Question before that. Why are you providing a `window.location.href` instead of just a plain reloadGrid. What you can do is in your loadComplete you save a variable pageNo which will save the page number. and then set the page number and reload the grid. I put some sample code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x0xm6zbs/3/)